# iAds: How can I prevent my AdBannerView delegate from getting called after the view has been released?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, iad

I'm adding iAds to my app and it's crashing because the AdBannerView delegate gets called after the view is released.  I'm following the code examples in the Apple docs, as well as code samples I've found on the Apple Dev forums, but I'm missing something because it's crashing.

I create the AdBannerView in the viewDidLoad of the view I want display it in...

```
self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
self.adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 66)];
adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape];
adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
adView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:adView];
```

I bring it to the front in the viewDidAppear...

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:[self adView]];
adView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, adView.frame.size.width, adView.frame.size.height);
```

I set it to nil in the viewDidUnload...

```
[[self adView] setDelegate:nil];
[self setAdView:nil];
```

and I release it in dealloc...

```
[adView release];
```

Yet, every now and then, the app crashes with this error...

```
-[MyViewController bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xf61d820
```

What am I missing?

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that `viewDidUnload` never gets called, if the view controller winds up being released before ever unloading the view. You will need to set the delegate to nil in dealloc too.

---

Also, I notice your memory handling of the ad view is wrong. I suspect that your `adView` property is declared `retain` and not `assign`. If so, then after this line

```
self.adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 66)];
```

the "retain count" (not to be confused with the `retainCount` property, which should be ignored) of the ad banner is now two: one from the alloc and one from the assignment to the property. If it gets to `viewDidUnload`, then `[self setAdView:nil]` releases it once but then the reference is lost so the release in `dealloc` can never release it again to bring the "retain count" back to zero.

If, on the other hand, your `adView` actually is declared `assign` rather than `retain`, it's still wrong. In that case, `[self setAdView:nil]` in `viewDidUnload` drops the reference without ever releasing it, leaking the ad view.

Comment: Thanks, Anomie, for catching that.  I just fixed it and so far the crash isn't occuring, but it was intermittent to begin with, so I'll let you know if it's still happening.  Thanks again!